# What's wrong with my ActionScript Regex?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying pull a field out of a string and return it.

My function:

```
public function getSubtype(ut:String):String {
            var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("X=(\w+)","i");
            var nut:String = ut.replace(pattern, "$1");
            trace("nut is " + nut);
            return nut;
        }
```

I'm passing it the string:

```
http://foo.bar.com/cgi-bin/ds.pl?type=boom&X=country&Y=day&Z=5
```

the trace statements return the above string with out modification.

I've tried the pattern out on Ryan Swanson's Flex 3 Regular Expresion Explorer and it returns: X=country.  My wished for result is "country".

Must be obvious, but I can't see it.  Any help will be appreciated.

TB

changed my function to the following and it works:

```
public function getSubtype2(ut:String):String {
            trace("searching " + ut);
            var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("X=([a-z]+)");
            var r:Object = pattern.exec(ut);
            trace("result is " + r[1]);
            return r[1].toString();
```

Interestingly, though, using X=(\w+) does not match and causes an error.  ????
            }

Comment: Yes, that's a better way. And if AS is like Java, you have to try: new RegEx("X=(\\w+)", "i");

Comment: Though the adobe docs use \w+ as an example.

Comment: In a *regex literal* you use one backslash: `/X=(\w+)/`. You're writing it as a *string* literal to pass it to the RegExp constructor: `new RegExp("X=(\\w+)")`; that's why you have to use two backslashes. ref: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/RegExp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace method is used for replacing. That is if you want to modify the given string. Replacing given portion with his own occurrence produces the same string.
I think you are looking for the match method, that produces an array of matches, see below.

```
function getSubtype(ut:String):String {
            var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("X=([a-z]+)","i");
            var nut:Array = ut.match(pattern);
            trace("nut is " + nut[1]);
            return nut[1];
}
```

nut[0] beeing the full matched string, followed by nut[1] the first brackets group and so on.

Comment: Also, in order for your first pattern with \w to work, if you write it between quotes, then you must escape the \ char. Else it would work only if written like
var pattern:RegExp = /X=(\w+)/;

Comment: Thanks a bunch! All the wrinkles to learning a new language :-)

Answer (score 1):

The replace method does not mutate the string it operates on, it returns a new string.  Try:-

```
var nut:String = ut.replace(pattern, "$1");
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion.  Unfortunately, still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't know ActionScript...

Your RE Explorer seems to return the matched pattern, see if there is a possibility to see the captures as well.

And if AS behaves like most languages I know, your replace() call replaces `X=country` with `country`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("X=(\w+)","i");
```

You can write this:

```
 var pattern:RegExp = /X=(\w+)/i;
```

Then you will not have problems with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern : RegExp = /[\\?&]X=([^&#]*)/g;
var XValue : String = pattern.exec(ut)[1];
```

See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/RegExp.html#exec%28%29 for further explanations.

I have also found this [flex regexp testing tool](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) to be quite helpful.